# Using sed with non-printable characters

Tags: regex, unix, sed

I'm having trouble using sed to replace non-printable characters with other non-printable characters.
Specifically, I want sed to look for a line in a table starting with a TAB and 'insert' a BACKSPACE, essentially bringing the text from that line up to the previous line.

The reason for this is that I have a table split into columns, with some rows taking up multiple lines:

```
column1,row1    column2,row1,line1
                column2,row1,line2
```

I'd like it to end up like this (ish)

```
column1,row1    column2,row1,line1         column2,row1,line2
```

(the spacings don't matter)

I can't seem to manage this though. I'm unsure if the expressions \t sand \b aren't recognized, but they don't seem to be in the way I've tried. I also can't get echo commands with octal representations of these

These are the kind of things I've tried:

```
sed 's/^\t/\b/' file.txt newfile.txt


sed 's/^(`echo "\011"`)/`echo "\010"`/' file.txt newfile.txt
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you really want to "insert a backspace", or would it be sufficient to remove the newline?  I mean, is your end-goal to have single lines comprised of what was spread over two lines before, or do you want actual Ctrl-H's inserted?

Comment: I've tried to show above what I'd like to happen. I'd like the the lines that are indented (with tabs) to be aligned with the second column to go onto the same line as the one above, so that each 'row' only takes up one line. Sorry if it was unclear.

Comment: I think you're mixing up the "BACKSPACE" ASCII character, Ctrl-H, and the editor command "backspace", usually assigned to backspace key and to ctrl-h key combination.

Inserting BACKSPACE character does not magically remove previous character. You need to be running an editor and pressing ctrl and H together to make the editor remove the character.

What you really need to do is to replace \n\t with \t. I don't have time to test the exact code - could someone else please provide that answer?

Comment: @Arkadiy `sed $'s/\n\t/\t/' file.txt > newfile.txt` Is this right?

Comment: @user1488804 - you've clarified your requirements in comments, but you haven't updated your question.  Please click the [**edit**](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/11450514/edit) link under your question and update your question.  Also, this is an [XY problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem).

Comment: I am not sure if sed can treat \n as any other character - I'd have to verify that. Normally \n receives special treatment: it's considered a line separator rather than a part of contents.

Comment: @Arkadiy - you're right, I think a solution in sed would need to use the N command which joins lines.  The catch is that you want to join only if the NEXT line (which sed hasn't seen yet) starts with whitespace. That's why ghoti was talking about the hold buffer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't do this with sed.  Sure, it's possible to have sed store a line in a hold buffer, then read the next line and if it starts with whitespace, pop and print the hold buffer then print the current line ... but the code will look like your modem just lost carrier.

I'd use awk.

```
awk '/^[^ \t]/ && buf{print buf;buf=""} {buf=buf $0} END{print buf}' input.txt
```

**What does this do?**

- The second section, `{buf=buf $0}`, adds the current line to a buffer named `buf`.
- Then, the first section, `/^[^ \t]/ && buf{print buf;buf=""}` (which is ignored for the first line because `buf` has not yet been set), prints `buf` for any line that doesn't start with whitespace (i.e. the start of a new output line).  Then it resets `buf`.
- The last section, `END{print buf}`, prints any leftovers.

Answer (score 1):

This is very ugly use of sed, but works:

```
 echo "a
 <TAB here>b
 <TAB here>c
 <TAB here>d
 e" | sed ':begin N; /\n\t/'\!'n;  s/\n\t//; t begin'
```

`bash` gets credit for the ugly escaping of the `\!` sign. In a script, you can leave it away.

Comment: I pasted your command in to my script `sed ':begin N;/\n\t/'\!'n;s/\n\t//;t begin' <test1.txt >test2.txt` but nothing changed after running it. I must be doing something wrong but I don't know what.

Comment: Probably you don't have tabs but spaces in your file?

Comment: There aren't any spaces in the file, all tabs. I have just made sure and the same things happens. I think that bash is having trouble understanding the \n and \t characters and is just ignoring them.

Comment: No, bash has no trouble. Try again on your file: `sed ':begin N; /\n\t/'\!'n;  s/\n\t//; t begin' yourfile.txt`

Comment: The same thing happens. All of the indented text stays exactly where it is

Comment: There is something strange with your setup. Try to understand the sed line and make up one that's working for you.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '$!N;s/\n\t/\t/;P;D' file
```